# Blazor Task With Wrong Return Type

Tags: c#, task, return-type, blazor

I am getting the error

> Task>
>   __generated__Index.SearchFilms(string)' has the wrong return type

On my code below and I don't know why. The line in question is

```
 <BlazoredTypeahead SearchMethod="SearchFilms"
```

Code:

```
@page "/"

@using Blazored.Typeahead

<BlazoredTypeahead SearchMethod="SearchFilms"
                   @bind-Value="SelectedFilm">
    <SelectedTemplate>
        @context.Title
    </SelectedTemplate>
    <ResultTemplate>
        @context.Title (@context.Year)
    </ResultTemplate>
</BlazoredTypeahead>

@if (SelectedFilm != null)
{
    <p>Selected Film is: @SelectedFilm.Title</p>
}



@code {

    private List<Film> Films;
    private Film SelectedFilm;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Films = new List<Film> {
            new Film("The Matrix", 1999),
            new Film("Hackers", 1995),
            new Film("War Games", 1983) };
    }

    private async  Task<List<Film>> SearchFilms(string searchText)
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(Films.Where(x => x.Title.ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower())).ToList());
    }

    class Film
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }

        public Film(string title, int year)
        {
            Title = title;
            Year = year;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Introduction

On `BlazoredTypeahead` the `SearchMethod` is async because this delegate is intended to call backend for data and **we can't block the UI thread** waiting for result. Typically:

```
private async  Task<IEnumerable<Film>> SearchFilms(string searchText)
{
    try
    {
       var result = await BackendService.SearchFilms(searchText);
       return result;
    } 
    catch ( ... )
    {
         UiShowError( ... )
         return empty_list;
    }
}
```

But in your case, **no backend operations are involved** and your whole method is sync. Then, compiler will raise warning because they are not any `async` operation into your method.

Also, [quoting docs](https://github.com/Blazored/Typeahead/blob/master/README.md):

> You must provide a method which has the following signature `Task<IEnumerable<T> MethodName(string searchText)`, to the SearchMethod parameter.

#### Solution

One easy and readable solution is to make an `async` call in your method:

```
private async  Task<IEnumerable<Film>> SearchFilms(string searchText)
{
    var result = Films
                 .Where(x => x.Title.ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower()))
                 .ToList();
    await Task.CompletedTask;  // avoid warning (*1)
    return result;
}
```

But they are other more  ways to do it: you can micro-optimized and avoid `async` and convert `result` into a `task`, see [aguas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57992338/842935).

(*1) *Also you can avoid warning writing `#pragma warning disable CS1998` above the method (thanks [@Henk Holterman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60761/henk-holterman) )*

Comment: dani, you should never  await a Task.CompletedTask; Read this: http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/should-i-await-on-task-fromresult-method-calls

Comment: This looks like it does exactly the same as the code in the question, I don't see the explanation part. @Alec: does this run with  `List<Film>` instead of `IEnumerable<Film>` ?

Comment: @Issac, exactly, never into an async method.

Comment: You can remove (elide) the async&await keywords, see @agua's anwser.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, sure you are right. Any case, I prefer to await CompletedTask, (in my opinion) it is more readable and works even for "void" return ( How would you do it if instead `Task<List<Film>>` was just `Task`? ) also [performance is the same or better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30493295/842935) (?),

Comment: removing `async` is always a (small) optimization. I would usually go for the least detours. And you can just return a CompletedTask without awaiting it, for "just Task".

Comment: Of course @HenkHolterman, it's a micro-optimization also is coherent with types and calls. Returning Task without async is what compiler wants. I prefer my readability :(

Comment: OK, but how is this (fundamentally) different from the question?  The OP was "emulating" async as well. I still don't see the crucial part.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, OMG: _You must provide a method which has the following signature Task<IEnumerable<T> MethodName(string searchText), to the SearchMethod parameter._

Comment: Still one more thing about the eliding stuff: You are not `// emulating async`, you are supressing a Warning. That line has no real purpose. A `#pragma warning disable CS1998` above the method might be the least fake way to do this.

Comment: Hallo @HenkHolterman, thanks again about your comments, always learning from you. I rewrite answer. I hope will be better now.

Comment: So you know guys the method was async as there will be a network task in there eventually.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using an asynchronous method in your private method. The code should be :

```
private Task<List<Film>> SearchFilms(string searchText)
{
    return Task.FromResult(Films.Where(x => x.Title.ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower())).ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by changing the SearchFilms method to the one below, weird.

```
    private async Task<IEnumerable<Film>> SearchFilms(string searchText) 
{
    return await Task.FromResult(Films.Where(x => x.Title.ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower())).ToList());
}
```

Comment: Alec, it runs but you don't know way. I explained it on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57992272/842935)