# Does await Task.CompletedTask mean the async method will run synchronously?

Tags: c#, async-await, task

```
static async Task WaitTaskCompleted()
{
    //Use Thread A before await Task.CompletedTask
    await Task.CompletedTask;
    //Will the code after await Task.CompletedTask always use Thread A, or there is chance to have a Thread B?
}
```

which means `await Task.CompletedTask` will always actually perform the method synchronously?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30493036/ In this case the method need not be async, and the Completed Task need not be awaited.

Comment: agreed; to echo @StuartLC's point: this could be just `/* stuff here */ return Task.CompletedTask;` with no `async` modifier

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, this code will always run synchronously; the main continuation compiler goo is only invoked when the first *incomplete* awaitable is encountered.

You can see this in [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABADAAgwRgFYBuAWACgMBmPAJhwGEcBvCndvfJPADj24DqAQwCWAFwxIGEALYAHADYwxMACYAKAJRsOrchwM4A9EYCqAZxg4AKgAtYQ1TgCCOYDABm0KxgCc/ADppeSUVVUkdQzx/SSDZRWU1STJ9KOMjAREFBRwxWytIVSshDxUoaMDghLDJHCEFAHchAE9zHABXSxt7GEcXABocaFz82BwRNrBbIQA7MCsxCBxpgDdi7ocnACEAfkicAF8KA6A==) - in particular, here:

```cs
awaiter = Task.CompletedTask.GetAwaiter();
if (!awaiter.IsCompleted)
{
    num = (<>1__state = 0);
    <>u__1 = awaiter;
    <>t__builder.AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted(ref awaiter, ref this);
    return;
}
```

It is the `AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted(...)` + `return` that implements asynchronicity.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sanity of other readers, the usual purpose of `Task.FromResult<T>`, `Task.CompletedTask`, `Task.FromCancelation` and `Task.FromException()` is to provide simple factory methods for various types of `Task` (i.e. with / without return payload, or to return an exception or mimic cancellation), and in all cases, the tasks returned will be regarded as `IsCompleted`, as per [the source:](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/tasks/Task.cs,6976f9b4eee09718)

```
private const int TASK_STATE_COMPLETED_MASK = TASK_STATE_CANCELED | TASK_STATE_FAULTED 
                                              | TASK_STATE_RAN_TO_COMPLETION;
```

As per @Marc's answer, awaiting an already `IsCompleted` Task short circuits the awaiter and execution will continue synchronously on the same thread.

As per my comment, it would be highly unusual to directly `await` a Task created by `Task.CompletedTask` or `Task.FromResult`, as this compiler would generate an unnecessary [async state machine wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54351439), which is total overkill in the OP's scenario.

A common scenario for using the various completed Task factory methods would be in mocking during Unit testing, where the class / interface being mocked requires a `Task` to be returned but otherwise has no need for `async`. For example, if the following production interface needed mocking or stubbing:

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
     Task<DateTime> GetDateAsync();
}
```

which could be stubbed as follows:

```
public class MyMock : ISomeInterface
{
    public Task<DateTime> GetDateAsync() // no async
    {
        // Directly return a completed task return a fake result
        return Task.FromResult(new DateTime(2019, 11, 12, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc));
    }
}
```

The production class being tested (SUT) would then likely await the result of `GetDateAsync()` on the injected (and now mocked) `ISomeInterface`, and will usually be none the wiser that the called method just **rubber stamped** the Task and returned fake data synchronously.